# Preposition with time

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

I am just confused about these rules. I've learned that we can use

> I will be there by 9 p.m.

to mean that I promise to be there before 9 p.m.

Can we use the following two statements instead? If not why?

> I will be there at 9 p.m.
>
> I will be there before 9 p.m.

I am not sure why don't we use these to be specific about the time I will be there (or I will be back)

Answer (score 2):

We can use all these statements, with slightly different shades of meaning.

If something important is going to happen at nine o'clock, you can promise to be there at that time; but, if you don't know *exactly* how long the journey will take and intend to give yourself plenty of time, you can say you will be there *by* 9.00 (you may arrive early).

If you plan to allow yourself so much time that you are sure to arrive early, you could say "I will be there before 9.00."

Answer (score 0):

A programme is going to take place at 9 p.m.

I will be there **at** 9 p.m. (I will be there at that time)

I will be there **by** 9 p.m. I will be there **before** 9 p.m. (I will be there at 8 p.m. or at 8:30 p.m. *deadline- 9 p.m.)

by - not later than

before - earlier than the time